# Make your Screensaver as a Wallpaper in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, screensaver, desktop-customization

I have an ASUS laptop, a **G75V** model. It has 16GB Ram, 2TB of HD space, and a 2GB 660M video card. It is also a 17" LCD at 1080 DPI resolution. It has an Intel i7 processor in it. So what I think I am asking is quite possible with the system I have in my possession.

In Windows there is a way to make your screensaver appear to be your desktop wallpaper, without actually being it.

Using this command in the command prompt. `scrnsvr.scr /p65802` your screensaver of choice will overlap your desktop, but not become it.

In OS X, it is very simple to make your screensaver override your desktop wallpaper by typing this in your terminal:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background`

In Windows it seems to be impossible...

Without using a 3rd party application, is there actually a way to make your screensaver into the actual wallpaper?

This is what I'm talking about: http://www.3planesoft.com/clock-screensavers/mechanical-clock-3d-screensaver/

What I don't want to do though is buy the app just to trick the OS to do what it seems to be able to do naturally with a purchase of an app, does this make any sense to anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've got this right. Do you want to have an animated background kind of thing going on? Also OSX tag isn't really relevant. P.S Hiii. Nice to see you again.

Comment: OS X is relevant because I wanted to have an example of how I want it to work on Windows. 

I have an animated background but it's not really a background, it's the app running over the desktop. I actually can't see the desktop icons at all, unless I hide the app..  

BTW, good to see you again too :)

Comment: Re-tagged as OS X is not relevant to the actual question. The tags should correspond to the target OSes on which the solution should work. The command-line tag is also not relevant unless you're looking *only* for command-line based solutions.

Comment: The closest that Windows has come to this feature was the 'Dreamscene' extra that came with Windows Vista Ultimate, and allowed active desktop backgrounds. This feature was discontinued after Vista due to unpopularity. Your best bet would be to go find one of the third party "Dreamscene activators" that purport to restore that functionality to later versions of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it explained here: [Run Screensaver as Wallpaper in Windows 8 and 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-screensaver-as-wallpaper-windows)

> In Windows 8 and Windows 7, you can run the screensaver as your
> desktop wallpaper, while allowing the mouse to move, without any
> 3rd-party application.
>
> To do this, open a Command Prompt window.
> type the name of the screen-saver followed by the switch **/p65552**
> and hit Enter. This switch for the screen saver allows for the application to
> run even while the mouse is being moved.
>
> For example to run the  Bubbles or Aurora screensaver as your wallpaper
> type : bubbles.scr /p65552 or aurora.scr /p65552 respectively.
>
> ...

(The result is "so so" imho...)

Comment: Please add the contents of the link into your answer... If link rot occurs, your answer will have limited value.

Comment: OK: good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

No, not without using a third party program.  Windows does not provide that functionality.